# iOS backend service manual data storage

Tags: ios, iphone, service, parse-platform, backend

I've searched about best iPhone backend services and best recommended are parse.com, stackmob... But what I'm interested is which one is best for storing own data by hand and then using that data for iOS ?

As I read the docs on all of these sites they are always refering to saving games data or any other data from the iPhone to the backend. But I would like to store my own data manually (so on www.parse.com website for example) on that backend and then use it/retrieve it on iPhone. Is that good aproach? Are those backends even used for those kind of stuff or should I create my own database for that?

If they are used, which one is the best? From all the recommendations and reviews looks like parse.com is prolly the best one.

Thanks.

Comment: I've used an `ASP.Net` and `SQL Server` backend for my iPad app. Reasonably simple to set up and seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Are those expensive? Since these ones are free :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, manually typing into Parse.com could be tedious although it is allowed with a clean UI. I suggest you put all your data in an Excel sheet, write an Excel formula to generate CURL commands and run the CURL command in a terminal that would save the data to your Parse.com account.

https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-creating

Comment: Great idea! But overall storing data manually on parse.com like that is okay?

Comment: @ŽeljaHuber Pushing data to Parse in such way is fine. I used the same process in pushing data manually.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
This question is old and parse.com is dead but there are many more options now.

1. Firebase
2. Use Swift Vapor/Perfect to create your own backend on AWS

Parse.com is good you can update data manually in parse.com table.

**steps** create parse.com account-> create your app -> click on the dashboard-> left side click to add class analogous to table-> add rows in your class manually or through API->fill data in columns.

Best part you don't have to pay till you generate enough traffic. so if your app is not a success you save on back-end development.
If on a later date you want higher capacity you can upgrade or you can export your database and port it to your own server.